# Gstreamer 1.0 no such or plugin 'videotestsrc' on buildroot problem

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, buildroot, gstreamer-1.0

I tried to play video with gstreamer-1.0 on buildroot. I opened elements of gstreamer on buildroot. But when I use `gst-inspect` command, I can not find elements what actived on buildroot. For example I activated `videotestsrc`. When I want use this element, I take `no such element or plugin 'videotestsrc'` error.

Also I tried export library. I used this command:

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/bin/gstreamer-1.0`
`export GST_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/bin/gstreamer-1.0`
`export GST_PLUGIN_1_0`

but result did not change. How can I fix this? How can I work gstreamer-1.0 on buildoot?

**Note:** Buildroot 2019.05-rc1, kernel 5.0.14, u-boot 2017-05, microprocess Allwinner A13

**Update(16.05.2019)**
defconfig:

```
BR2_arm=y
BR2_cortex_a8=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_LINUX_HEADERS_CUSTOM_4_11=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_BUILDROOT_WCHAR=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_BUILDROOT_CXX=y
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_HOSTNAME="GenOS"
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_ISSUE="Welcome to Mega7"
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_GETTY_PORT="ttyS0"
BR2_ROOTFS_POST_BUILD_SCRIPT="board/olimex/a13_olinuxino/post-build.sh"
BR2_ROOTFS_POST_IMAGE_SCRIPT="support/scripts/genimage.sh"
BR2_ROOTFS_POST_SCRIPT_ARGS="-c board/olimex/a13_olinuxino/genimage.cfg"
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_VERSION=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_VERSION_VALUE="4.11.5"
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_DEFCONFIG="sunxi"
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_DTS_SUPPORT=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_INTREE_DTS_NAME="sun5i-a13-olinuxino"
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_INSTALL_TARGET=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_FFMPEG_FFPLAY=y
BR2_PACKAGE_FFMPEG_AVRESAMPLE=y
BR2_PACKAGE_GSTREAMER1=y
BR2_PACKAGE_GST1_PLUGINS_GOOD=y
BR2_PACKAGE_GST1_PLUGINS_BAD=y
BR2_PACKAGE_GST1_PLUGINS_UGLY=y
BR2_PACKAGE_GST1_INTERPIPE=y
BR2_PACKAGE_GST1_LIBAV=y
BR2_PACKAGE_DIRECTFB=y
BR2_PACKAGE_MESA3D=y
BR2_PACKAGE_MESA3D_GALLIUM_DRIVER_SWRAST=y
BR2_PACKAGE_MESA3D_DRI_DRIVER_SWRAST=y
BR2_PACKAGE_MESA3D_OPENGL_EGL=y
BR2_PACKAGE_MESA3D_OPENGL_ES=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XORG7=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XSERVER_XORG_SERVER=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XAPP_SETXKBMAP=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XAPP_TWM=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XAPP_XCLOCK=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XAPP_XINIT=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XAPP_XRANDR=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_INPUT_KEYBOARD=n
BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_INPUT_MOUSE=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_FBDEV=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_FBTURBO=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XTERM=y
BR2_PACKAGE_OPENBOX=y
BR2_PACKAGE_PYTHON=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LIBDRM_NOUVEAU=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LIBGTK3=y
# BR2_PACKAGE_LIBGTK3_BROADWAY is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_LIBGTK3_WAYLAND is not set
BR2_PACKAGE_LIBGTK3_DEMO=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LIBSERIALPORT=y
BR2_PACKAGE_SCREEN=y
BR2_PACKAGE_SUDO=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HTOP=y
BR2_PACKAGE_NANO=y
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2=y
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_4=y
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_SIZE="300M"
BR2_TARGET_UBOOT=y
BR2_TARGET_UBOOT_BUILD_SYSTEM_KCONFIG=y
BR2_TARGET_UBOOT_CUSTOM_VERSION=y
BR2_TARGET_UBOOT_CUSTOM_VERSION_VALUE="2017.05"
BR2_TARGET_UBOOT_BOARD_DEFCONFIG="A13-OLinuXino"
BR2_TARGET_UBOOT_NEEDS_DTC=y
BR2_TARGET_UBOOT_SPL=y
BR2_TARGET_UBOOT_SPL_NAME="u-boot-sunxi-with-spl.bin"
BR2_TARGET_UBOOT_BOOT_SCRIPT=y
BR2_TARGET_UBOOT_BOOT_SCRIPT_SOURCE="board/olimex/a13_olinuxino/boot.cmd"
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_DOSFSTOOLS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_GENIMAGE=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_MTOOLS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_UBOOT_TOOLS=y
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your buildroot configuration exactly? (run make savedefconfig and paste the defconfig file here). Notice that Buildroot will not notice changes to the many gst1-plugins-* options after you have done a build, so you need to do a clean build (make clean; make) for the changes to take effect.

See the manual for details:
https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#full-rebuild

Comment: Updated my question. I'm using the pre-saved def config file. Because it takes too long to recompile the file def config. I cleaned buildroot, actually I remove buildroot file and downloaded again.

Comment: @Faruk, did you resolve your issue?  I'm having the same issue, but with audiotestsrc, autoaudiosink, and alsasink, as well as some others.  I'm using Buildroot 2020.02.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok, you are missing the videotestsrc option under gst1-plugins-base: BR2_PACKAGE_GST1_PLUGINS_BASE_PLUGIN_VIDEOTESTSRC=y

Comment: Thanks @PeterKorsgaard, running (make clean; make) fixed the issue.  Thanks!